# multiples removevalue() from Firebase not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code works this way: when I'm on a post and I press "ok" on a AlertDialog.Builder then I go to:

```
private void borrar_post(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(PostDetailActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_BORRAR_POST", mPostKey);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

I come back to main activity and I see if there's anything I need to delete:

```
String borrar = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_BORRAR_POST");

    if (borrar != null) {

        DatabaseReference mipost = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mipost.child("user-posts").child(getUid()).child(borrar).removeValue();

        mipost.child("posts").child(borrar).removeValue();

        mipost.child("post-comments").child(borrar).removeValue();

    }
```

I delete my post from the 3 places I have it on my firebase realtime database. The tree is:

[image: Firebase Tree]

It's possible I don't have anything on "post-comments", so I understand I might have a problem there (maybe I should check if there's something there before) but even when I comment that line, I keep having the same problem:

Sometimes everything gets deleted, sometimes nothing, most of the times only "user-posts" child gets deleted.

I know there's similar questions to mine, but I can't seem to find the mistake, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have security rules that limit write access as a function of the current value at a location?  That might explain why some removes succeed and others fail.

To understand why some calls to `removeValue()` are failing, add a [CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener).  You can define a debug listener as a field in your activity like this:

```
private DatabaseReference.CompletionListener mRemoveListener =
        new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
        if (error == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Removed: " + ref);
            // or you can use:
            System.out.println("Removed: " + ref);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Remove of " + ref + " failed: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Then add it to each of your calls to `removeValue()`:

```
String borrar = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_BORRAR_POST");

if (borrar != null) {
    // always good to log important values
    Log.d(TAG, "borrar= " + borrar);

    DatabaseReference mipost = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mipost.child("user-posts").child(getUid()).child(borrar).removeValue(mRemoveListener);

    mipost.child("posts").child(borrar).removeValue(mRemoveListener);

    mipost.child("post-comments").child(borrar).removeValue(mRemoveListener);
}
```

Comment: I'll try that, but regarding "security rules that limit write access as a function of the current value at a location"I think I have not... how should implement it? with mutexes? maybe with something from firebase?

Comment: I've tried to delete it 2 posts this way and I only get the "borrar=" message and then it crashes before getting any log from the remove listener: https://image.ibb.co/bD3H8F/screenshot_544.jpg

Comment: Post the log output from the crash.  There should be a stack trace or exception message.

Comment: This is a pretty good way as it is showing the complete node address that has to be removed